# how to use Example table (Parametrised Scenarios) with normal "Given" statement

Tags: java, spring, bdd, jbehave

when I am trying to run below story file, statement "**a stock of**" executing two time but I want that this execution should happen only once and statement "**reference data databasetable record  with sds id =  and swift bic =** " should execute twice.

```
Scenario: Parametrised Scenarios Test

Given scenario parameter - swiftBic = JBEHAVEXXX
Given scenario parameter - receiverBic = JBEHAVEYYY
Given scenario parameter - extSdsId = 1111
Given scenario parameter - sdsId = 22222

Given reference data databasetable record <alias> with sds id = <sId> and swift bic = <bic>
Given a stock of.

Examples:
|alias  |sId            |bic            |
|DEF    |${sdsId}       |${swiftBic}    |
|DEFF   |${extSdsId}    |${receiverBic} |
```

Comment: I'm assuming that your feature has some actual `When` and `Then` conditions in real world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cucumber using `Example`s is a shortcut for writing the same scenario twice with different data. So you code above is equivilent to:

```
Scenario: test with fisrt set of data 
    Given reference data databasetable record DEF with sds id = 2222 and swift bic = JBEHAVEXXX
    Given a stock of.

Scenario: test with second set of data 
    Given reference data databasetable record DEF with sds id = 1111 and swift bic = JBEHAVYYY
    Given a stock of.
```

so if you only want the `Given a stock of.` step to execute once you cannot use the `Example` shortcut and will have to have two separate scenarios with explicit steps.